# Asp.net Change Password Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, change-password

In my asp.net Web app. I have a change password form that is not working properly. I set the LoginEvent cancel to false when it has changed. It changes ok, but the control thinks that it fails. Is there something else I need to do?

```
control.Objects.User user = GlobalClass.GlobalVariables.User;
    string currentRealPassword = control.Data.Users.GetUserPassword(user);
    if (user != null && ChangeUserPassword.CurrentPassword.Trim() == currentRealPassword)
    {
        e.Cancel = !control.Data.Users.UpdateUserPassword(user, ChangeUserPassword.NewPassword);
    }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Wrote it myslef instead of using memebership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm...the code doesn't helps:P
What "UpdateUserPassword" Returns? suppose bool.

One hint... C# is OOP:P

Are you comming from php?

Comment: Yes it returns a bool, and no I am not coming from php. I have never used this control before and I am looking at examples and following every step. If that event is not canceled it suppose to be successful but its not either way. I even set the property in the membership in web config file

Comment: Have you add a break point to the source to see the returned values?